# can someone explain the proof of russels paradox (barber)?

Tags: logic, paradoxes

So I understand Russels paradox (barber) but I do not understand the proof, I've looked everywhere online and youtube videos but it doesn't seem to make sense.

Please note, I have compensated dyslexic so I find it hard to interpret and understand text. I think this is the reason why I am finding it difficult to understand the proof.

This is as much as I understand:  P(x) <----> x is not a member of itself. What I don't understand is if it means the element x is not a member of itself? And if so, I do not understand how a element can be a member of itself.

Comment: The issue with trying to find a set that is an element of itself isn't really possible, with the traditional definition of a set (in fact, in ZFC there is an axiom which implies that a set cannot be an element of itself).  However, the axioms for Naive Set Theory (which is the setting of Russell's Paradox) don't forbid it, so there *could* be really weird sets out there that are elements of themselves, and in fact in Naive Set Theory the universe is a set (and hence contains itself); Russell's Paradox shows that this is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Don't get hung up on the set-theoretic $\in$ relation. The proof works for every binary relation.

Consider the statement: $$\exists r: \forall x:[E(x,r) \iff \neg E(x,x)]$$ where $E$ is just some logical predicate having nothing to do with set membership.

Show how, from the above statement, you can obtain the contradiction: $$E(r,r) \iff \neg E(r,r)$$ What would this tell you about the original statement?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use set-theoretic notation for the barber paradox. The proof is just:

Take any barber who cuts the hair of exactly those who don't cut their own hair.

Either the barber cuts his own hair or he does not.

If he does cut his own hair, then by his own rule he is not supposed to cut his hair.

If he does not cut his own hair, then by his own rule he is supposed to cut his hair.

In all cases we get a contradiction, and so such a barber does not exist.

Comment: Using a set-theoretic analysis, you can assume the existence of a barber who is man in the village ($barber\in village$) and show that there cannot exist a relation $shaves$ among the men in the village that satisfies the requirement, $\forall x\in village:[(barber,x)\in shaves \iff (x,x)\notin shaves]$. See the video demo at my website http://www.dcproof.com

Comment: @DanChristensen: My point is that it is unnecessary to use set theory. One could also use type theory, or just first-order logic, or ... But the actual content of the barber paradox has nothing to do with any of them.

Comment: My point is that you can obtain more "solutions" using set theory. Using only FOL, you can only conclude that the barber does not exist -- not a very satisfying conclusion IMO. Using set theory, you could also conclude that no shaving relation can possibly satisfy the given requirements. That makes more sense. It points to an actual solution to the dilemma: change the requirements for the shaving relation.

Comment: @DanChristensen: "Such a barber does not exist" is a perfect satisfying conclusion. If it isn't, then "Such a shaving relation does not exist" is equally unsatisfying. You can't say that using set theory points to an actual solution without also saying that first-order logic does the same: change the requirements for the barber!!

Comment: @DanChristensen: I've also seen your attempts at formal proofs and your other questions on Math SE, and I recommend that you work through at least an equivalent of an undergraduate mathematics course, so that you get a better overall picture. It is well-known that most mathematicians do not have the slightest idea what ZFC is, nor do they need it. There are reasons for that, but to appreciate those reasons you would need to learn enough of various branches of mathematics first.

Comment: There is no need to invoke to any axioms of set theory here, only that you be able to quantify over relations (i.e. over sets of ordered pairs). Then you would be able to see that for a given man B in a village, there cannot exist a  relation S such that for any man X in  that village, (B,X) in S <=> (X,X) not in S. You could not formulate a similar conclusion using only  FOL because you cannot quantify over predicates. IMO, restricting yourself to solutions using only FOL is like having one arm tied behind your back.

Comment: As for the work of mathematicians, I doubt you will find even one who would forgo set theory and  restrict himself to using only FOL.

Comment: @DanChristensen: You are absolutely wrong. You cannot quantify exactly what sets are allowed in ZFC from within ZFC itself. Go and take a real class in set theory. In particular, learn properly what the axiom of comprehension means, and you will see that the axiom cannot be stated in ZFC itself.

Comment: @DanChristensen: As for mathematicians, I never said that they will only work in first-order logic, but that they do not normally care about ZFC. You made a false implication.

Comment: In a formal proof, I can certainly generalize: $\forall barber: \forall village:[barber \in village \implies \neg\exists S:\forall x \in village:[(barber,x)\in S \iff (x,x)\notin S]]$.

Comment: I don't think you can derive the equivalent statement in FOL.

Comment: @DanChristensen: "$\neg \exists x \forall y [ P(x,y) \leftrightarrow \neg P(y,y)]$" where $P$ is a binary predicate is a valid and provable sentence. If you insist I cannot use any predicates, then I insist that you cannot use $\in$, which is intrinsically nothing more than a binary predicate. In ZFC $\in$ is not even an ordinary relation but a proper class, which makes things more ugly than it needs to be. Furthermore, in higher-order logic one can fully state what you want. The exact statement depends on the type of higher-order logic, but my point is that it is far more intuitive than ZFC.

Comment: As in my answer here, the proof of my generalization does not make use of any axioms of set theory. It would be true for any binary predicate $\in$.

Comment: @DanChristensen: Yes, but for a mathematical model to represent the real-world situation, you need some kind of interpretation and that interpretation does not come easily for ZFC. Without any interpretation whatever sentence won't have any meaning. Why don't you look up higher-order logic? Then you will see that it can also quantify over what you want, and in a more intuitive way than ZFC. My whole point from the beginning is that forcing the barber paradox into a set-theory framework is pointless unless you pre-commit to set theory.

Comment: Higher order logic (quantifying over predicates)  is not widely used. I think I will stick to FOL and set theory, thanks.

Comment: @DanChristensen: Well you're not alone, since most set theorists and logicians just stick to first-order logic and set theory, but I was just saying that in practice mathematicians don't think in terms of full ZFC but quite in terms of higher-order logic. For instance the induction axiom is to most mathematicians simply a second-order axiom, and they don't think of it as a first-order axiom schema, nor do they know the ZFC axiom of infinity (that states that there is an inductive set).

Comment: @DanChristensen: A good example is to prove that the Hydra game always ends. It has a simple proof by second-order induction, but no proof exists in Peano arithmetic with only a first-order induction schema. Furthermore, although it would technically be possible to state and prove it in strict ZFC, it would be very painful both to formalize it and to read such a formalization.